# How to integrate with derivates on both sides

Tags: integration

I tried using integrating factor on both sides for this equation.

$$(t+1)\frac{dy}{dt} + y = \frac{dx}{dt} + x$$

but I got

$$e^t \times \frac{d((t+1) y)}{dt} = \frac{d(e^t  x)}{dt}$$

I dont know how to proceed. Could someone explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure about your integrating factor. It makes sense to consider the left and right sides of this equation as derivatives of a product. Notice that $$(t+1)\frac{dy}{dt}+y=\frac{d}{dt}[(t+1)y]$$ and $$\frac{dx}{dt}+x=\frac{d}{dt}[tx]$$
Thus, $$(t+1)\frac{dy}{dt}+y=\frac{dx}{dt}+x$$ $$\frac{d}{dt}[(t+1)y]=\frac{d}{dt}[tx]$$ $$(t+1)y=tx+C$$

Comment: Ohh okay thanks! :D Yeah I missed that.
But assuming that the final equation to be solved was the one in que, how do you think I should proceed?

Comment: Beautiful...but must exists a way where you dont need to see that it is the derivative of a product, maybe?